# How to share files between 2 ubuntu PC's

Tags: 14.04

I'm very new to the world of Linux and Ubuntu and just for fun I've built 2 ubuntu servers in which one will home torrents and the other will be a download server. However, if I use qbittorrent and ask it to load torrents from my torrent server it advises that it cannot be shared!

Basically I want the 2 PCs to talk to each other

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Linux servers use NFS to share filesystems.  Each server needs to 'export' desired directories for 'mounting' by the other server.

start by installing needed packages on each server:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

Let's say you have server 'A' and you want to share directory 'Green'
server 'B' has directory 'Red' to share.

Setup 'exports' On Server A:

```
sudo mkdir /exports
sudo mkdir /exports/Green
sudo echo "/exports/share1 *(rw,insecure,no_subtree_check)" >> /etc/exports

sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

Place the files you want to share in /exports/Green

Repeat for Server B, changing Green to Red.

Can we see the exports:

```
showmount -e <your_server_ip>
```

Now setup servers to 'mount' the exported dirs.

On server A (notice A is mounting from B):

```
sudo mkdir /Red
sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 <server_B_ip>:/exports/Red /Red
```

Repeat for server B:

```
sudo mkdir /Green
sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 <server_A_ip>:/exports/Green /Green
```

The mount will not persist across reboot, so you'll need to add to /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

Work through the Quick Start section of this :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

The page includes a more expansive treatment you might find interesting once you have the simple case working.

On one host you create a public directory then mount into that directory the directory you want to share. Then other hosts on the same network can mount that public directory as one of their own.   The process involves a couple or three configuration files that have some picky syntax but you should be able to find examples easily enough.